# How can I print a formatted array in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I trying to write a web-scraper for wordreference.com, the code is this:

```py
import bs4,sys, requests
from urllib import request

def scraper():
    url=f"https://wordreference.com/iten/{sys.argv[1]}"
    r=requests.get(url)
    html=r.text
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    x=soup.find_all("td","ToWrd")
    print(x[1].contents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper()
```

The code is right but the output is this:
input:

```
python3 scraper.py cane
```

Output:

```
['dog ', <em class="tooltip POS2">n<span><i>noun</i>: Refers to person, place, thing, quality, etc.</span></em>]]
```

I want print only the first part of array, when is contained 'dog'.
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

well here is the code:

```
print(x[1].contents[0])
```

x[1].contents returns a list, so to access the string 'dog ' , you need to specify index 0